# Parse map like json string into class by fastjson/jackson

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, fastjson

Consider a json:

```
{
  "data": {
    "key1": {
      "t1":"text1",
      "t2":"text1",
    },
    "key2": {
      "t1":"text1",
      "t2":"text1",
    },
    ...
  }
  "code": 1
}
```

With data java class defined as below:

```
  @Getter
  @Setter
  public class JsonData {
    private Data data;
    private int code;
  }

  @Getter
  @Setter
  public class Data {
    private Map<String, KeyInfo> mapKeyInfo;
  }

  @Getter
  @Setter
  public class KeyInfo {
    private String t1;
    private String t2;
  }
```

I try to get the JsonData object containing the json content but NullPointerException:

```
JsonData jsonData = JSONObject.parseObject(response, JsonData.class); // NullPointerException
```

What should I do if I want to do in fastjson way? What if I use jackson to do the same thing?

**Update**

I tried one class to parse but still failed:

```
  @Getter
  @Setter
  public class JsonData {
    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> data;
    private int code;
  }
```

Comment: I don't know the framework fastjson, but I think that your class `KeyInfo` should contain a `Map<String, String>` field instead of two `String` fields. Alternatively, the class `Data` contains a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` instead of a `Map<String, KeyInfo>`

Comment: can you try to initialize the Map in Data?   like mapKeyInfo = new HashMap<>();

Comment: Also, consider using `@Data` instead of just `@Getter` and `@Setter`.   it will include other usuful methods for data objects.   Also, consider the constructor annotations like `@AllArgsConstructor`   and  `@NoArgsConstructor`.   these are useful to have your object initialized in where frameworks requires it. (where they construct your class automatically).

Comment: @PamStums I tried but still the same